# Salesforce Approval Process Approver Field Query

Tags: apex

While creating an approval process 'Use Approver Field of Media Campaign Owner' is deactivated.

How to activate that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to Approval Flow that you have created for Media Campaign Object.
2. Click On Edit Entry Criteria of your approval flow.
3. Click Next and navigate to Step 3. Specify Approver Field and Record
   Editability Properties.
4. Under 'Select Field Used for Automated Approval Routing' there is an
   Option for 'Use Approver Field of Media Campaign Owner'.Set the
   value to true.
5. Click Save.

**Please note that Before Activating User Approval Field,You need to provide value in 'Provide Next Automated Approver Determined By'.**

> Approver Field of Media Owner checkbox becomes editable when you
>   select Manager or Custom User Field(if you define any) in the Next Automated Approver Determined By drop-down
>   list. When you select this checkbox, the approval request is routed to
>   the user specified in the Manager field on the record owner's user
>   record. If you don't select this checkbox, the approval request is
>   routed to the manager of the user submitting the record.

Hope this help